# Deblur images of a fast moving conveyor

Tags: python, opencv, motion-blur

I need to process a video stream of a belt conveyor for transporting coal, mainly to detect anomalies on the conveyor for safety reasons. Because of the conveyor's fast speed, all images are very blurry. The images are like this:

[image: blurry image]

I want to de-blur the images first, then run other object detection algorithms. I have tried the de-convolution script from [OpenCV](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.2.0/samples/python/deconvolution.py), the results aren't satisfying.

Any other algorithms or tools for this job?

Comment: Your link to your input image is broken. You need to use linear motion blur with a deconvolution filter. See skimage deconvolution at https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/filters/plot_deconvolution.html and https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.restoration.html#skimage.restoration.richardson_lucy and https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.restoration.html#skimage.restoration.unsupervised_wiener

Comment: Wikipedia has algorithm for [Unsharp Masking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsharp_masking) which can be implemented in OpenCV. But looking at the  image, the conveyor is so blurry that you might not get anything out of it.

Answer (score 0):

### Method 1

As you aim to deblur image for the sake of object detection, you can use [DeblurGAN](https://github.com/KupynOrest/DeblurGAN), A blind motion deblurring using conditional adversarial networks. They show how deblurring can significantly improve object detection model performance.

[image]

### Method 2

Also, you can try the [Photo Restoration](https://github.com/microsoft/Bringing-Old-Photos-Back-to-Life) method. It's able to remove **structured** and **unstructured** degradation effects in an image. An image like suffer from blurriness, noise, scratches, etc. Below is a quick output of your sample by this model. The right side is the raw blurry input and the left side is an enhanced version of it.

[image]